# HeatMapWithTime Plugin in Folium

Tags: python, python-3.x, heatmap, geopandas, folium

I was able to create a HeatMap but the points are not showing:

```
import folium
import folium.plugins as plugins
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from folium import Choropleth, Circle, Marker
from folium.plugins import HeatMap, MarkerCluster, HeatMapWithTime
ucdp_df = pd.read_csv('csv/ged201.csv') # from https://ucdp.uu.se/downloads/index.html#ged_global
ucdp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(ucdp_df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(ucdp_df.longitude, ucdp_df.latitude))
ucdp.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
m = folium.Map([35, 41], tiles='stamentoner', zoom_start=6)
hm = HeatMapWithTime(data=ucdp[['latitude', 'longitude']].values.tolist(),
                     index=ucdp['year'].values.tolist(), 
                     radius=10,
                     auto_play=True,
                     max_opacity=0.3)
hm.add_to(m)
m
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to provide the data in a correct format. This should work:

```py
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict

data = defaultdict(list)
for r in ucdp_df.itertuples():
    data[r.year].append([r.latitude, r.longitude])
    
data = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

Then use the data:

```py
m = folium.Map([35, 41],
               tiles='stamentoner',
               zoom_start=6)


hm = HeatMapWithTime(data=list(data.values()),
                     index=list(data.keys()), 
                     radius=10,
                     auto_play=True,
                     max_opacity=0.3)
hm.add_to(m)
m
```

and you get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps a lot.

Do you have any idea how can I make sure that the HeatMapWithTime always stays at the front of any other layers? I added an ImageOverlay and now the HeatmapWithTime is visualized in the back of overlay image. [Issue]: https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1400

Comment: Please, accept my answer if it solves your problem. For your additional request, open a new question. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65152407/order-layers-behind-heatmapwithtime-in-folium